# Text too small on lower resolution monitor in a dual display setup

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I put two monitor side-by-side and one has 4K resolution while the other one is 1080p. If I set the scale to 2X the text looks normal on the 4K monitor but everything looks too big on the 1080p monitor which makes it unusable. If I don't scale, the text on the 4K monitor will look too small. Since Ubuntu does not allow you to use different scale on different monitors, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

After tweaking xrandr for a few hours with no luck, I gave it up. But later on I found a solution which is pretty simple. This works if you have a Geforce graphic card and use Nvidia X Server Settings.

1. Install Nvidia graphic card driver and Nvidia X Server
2. Set the monitor with lower resolution as follows: (in the link)

The idea is to set ViewPortIn to the resolution of the higher display, and then set ViewPortOut to the actual physical resolution.

[image: Nvidia X Server Settings]